# How to get the value from Serializable class in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, getter-setter

I have a `fragment` which is handling `objects`. so i need to send the values Instance to OnCreateview() so i want to convert my serializable form, so i create these class with getter/setter

**BeanDemo.kt**

```
class BeanDemo : Serializable {

    var MyAppDatabase: AppDatabase ? = null

    constructor() {

    }

    //secoutry constructor

    constructor(appDatabase: AppDatabase){
        this. MyAppDatabase =  appDatabase
        Log.d("appDatabase : Bean", "appDatabase$appDatabase")
    }

    //getter/setter methods

    fun getName(): AppDatabase? {
        Log.d("appDatabase : getName", "appDatabase$MyAppDatabase")
        return MyAppDatabase
    }

    fun setName(NEWAPPDB: AppDatabase) {
        Log.d("appDatabase : NEWAPPDB", "appDatabase$NEWAPPDB")
        MyAppDatabase = NEWAPPDB
    }
}
```

**SendingFragment.kt**

```
class SendingFragment: Fragment(),Serializable
{

    private var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager? = null

    companion object {
        /**
         * new instance pattern for fragment
         */
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(myObject: List<TransactionEntity>?, cc: Context, appDatabase: AppDatabase, networkDefinitionProvider: NetworkDefinitionProvider, incoming: TransactionAdapterDirection): SendingFragment {

            val gson = Gson()
            val gson1 = GsonBuilder().create()

            val sampleVar = BeanDemo(appDatabase)
            sampleVar.setName(appDatabase)

            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putSerializable("serializedObject",sampleVar)
            val sendFragament = SendingFragment()
            sendFragament.arguments = bundle
            return sendFragament
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val beanDemo: BeanDemo
        val bundle = arguments
        beanDemo = bundle!!.getSerializable("serializedObject") as BeanDemo
        val name = beanDemo.getName()

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_fragment, container, false)
        val recyclerView = rootView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.transaction_recycler_out) as RecyclerView
        linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        //recyclerView.adapter = DuplicateTransactionRecyclerAdapter(NewIT,NewAPPDB,NewINCOMTYPE,NewNETWORKPROVSTR)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        return rootView
    }
}
```

The problem i can set the value in Instance of the class in fragment but i wan unable to get the data in OnCretaview().Null value is return. please guide me what i make mistakes. Thks in advance

**UPDATE**

```
@Database(entities = {AddressBookEntry.class, Token.class, Balance.class, TransactionEntity.class}, version = 1)
@TypeConverters({RoomTypeConverters.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase implements Serializable {

    public abstract AddressBookDAO getAddressBook();

    public abstract TokenDAO getTokens();

    public abstract TransactionDAO getTransactions();

    public abstract BalanceDAO getBalances();
}
```

Comment: Is `AppDatabase` instance of `RoomDatabase`? Is `AppDatabase` serializable?

Comment: Appdatabase no more serializable , thats why i create the class "BeanDemo "

Comment: can any one else to help to fix this ??

Comment: first thing do you really need to put BeanDemo object to bundle, instead you can create it on onCreateView() method

Comment: Okay , but how to get the `newInstance` args in OnCreateView() method??? is it possible without send the data using bundle ?? i dont think its possible . If i am wrong guide me

Answer (score 1):

If the class `AppDatabase` is not itself Serializable you cannot Serialice the `BeanDemo`.

Take also in account that when working with Bean like objects in kotlin you can use a data class (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) to avoid writting so much boilerplate. By doing:

```
data class BeanDemo(var MyAppDatabase: AppDatabase? = null) : Serializable()
```

You get among other things: setters, getters, equals(), hashCode() and toString() sensible implementations.

Also if you are working with Android please consider using Parcelable and the "Kotlin Android Extensions" (documentation here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) to work with Bundles.

Comment: Okay hanks for refernce links . If i make my Appdatabase class into serializable one how to pass the values????

Comment: if _Appdatabase_ and all its members are _Serializable_ your code above should work as far as I can tell.

Comment: Okay i update my question with Appdatabase , plz check it

Comment: in AppDatabase  file contains only interface then how o implement the seriaializable??